# Is it possible to pass though a template option to a module (as a variable parameter)

Tags: geb

I have a page that uses a module for defining form content. It is rather generically usable but needs different resulting pages after form actions have been triggered (button click, etc.).

```
class CreateOrganisationPage extends Page {
    static url = "#contact/organisation/create"

    static at = {
        form.displayed
    }

    static content = {
        form(wait: true) {
            module BusinessEntityFormModule, businessEntityName: 'organisation'
        }
    }
}
```

The module implementing the form content contains a UI control saveCommand that requires that a page `ViewBusinessEntityPage` is navigated to after submitting. In order to keep that module more **reusable** across different tests I wanted to provide that page as a **parameter**.
What is the best approach to do so?

```
class BusinessEntityFormModule extends Module {
    String businessEntityName = "entity"
    String idPrefix = "edit"
    static content = {
        self {
            def id = "$idPrefix-" + StringUtils.capitalize(businessEntityName)
            $("form", id: id)
        }

        saveCommand(to: ViewBusinessEntityPage) {
            $('[data-command="save"]')
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply define a property for the destination page in your module and use it in the content definition:

```
class BusinessEntityFormModule extends Module {
    Class postSavePage

    static content = {
         saveCommand(to: postSavePage) {
             $('[data-command="save"]')
         }
    }
}
```

And then set it when defining the module as part of the page:

```
class CreateOrganisationPage extends Page {
    static content = {
        form(wait: true) {
            module BusinessEntityFormModule, businessEntityName: 'organisation', postSavePage: ViewBusinessEntityPage
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I had tried but it seem that options are not evaluated against the the instance and therefore an exception is thrown:


``Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: postSavePage for class: de.troi.acceptancetest.contact.organisation.BusinessEntityFormModule
Possible solutions: postSavePage
 at groovy.lang.Closure.getPropertyTryThese(Closure.java:321)
 at groovy.lang.Closure.getPropertyOwnerFirst(Closure.java:315)
 at groovy.lang.Closure.getProperty(Closure.java:304)``

So it will only work with the property defined as static which defeats the purpose

Comment: This should work, at least in 0.10.0 which was released 2 weeks ago. There is [an issue I fixed](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GEB-245) that describes exactly what you are doing and there is [a test case for it](https://github.com/geb/geb/blob/master/module/geb-core/src/test/groovy/geb/PropertiesInModuleContentSpec.groovy#L41) that's passing. If it doesn't work in 0.10.0 then it's a bug and please create a new issue for it.

Comment: Ok, I'm still on 0.9.3 that explains a lot and really I should have mentioned it.

Comment: Even if you did I probably wouldn't remember that it didn't work in 0.9.3. I only started checking when it was fixed when you explicitly mentioned that the solution I would use doesn't work for you